# POSTGRESQL. Insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new in Posgresql. I have 5 tables and I am trying to INSERT properties to tables.  When I tried to Insert 2nd time, I have this error in 'pgadmin'.

`ERROR:  insert or update on table "question" violates foreign key constraint "question_id_difficulty_fkey" DETAIL:  Key (id_difficulty)=(9) is not present in table "difficulty". SQL state: 23503.`

my schema is here

```
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar
);

CREATE TABLE question (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  text varchar,
  correct_answer varchar,
  incorrect_answer1 varchar,
  incorrect_answer2 varchar,
  incorrect_answer3 varchar,
  id_difficulty SERIAL REFERENCES difficulty(id),
  id_category SERIAL REFERENCES category (id),
  id_creator SERIAL REFERENCES game (id)
);

CREATE TABLE difficulty (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar
);

CREATE TABLE category (
  id SERIAL PRIAMRY KEY,
  name varchar
);

CREATE TABLE user (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a corresponding entry in the difficulty table with an id of 9, so that a referencing id_difficulty column in the question table.

For example, if your difficulty table contained:

```
 id |      name      
----+----------------
  1 | easy
  2 | reasonable
  3 | difficult
  4 | very difficult
  5 | impossible
```

You could only set id_difficulty for rows in the question table to one of those id values.  If you set 6, or 12 or anything other than 1 to 5, it would fail because the values are constrained by the values in the foreign key.

The `id_difficulty`, `id_category` and `id_creator` columns shouldn't be using `serial`, so these should have their defaults dropped:

```
ALTER TABLE question ALTER COLUMN id_difficulty DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE question ALTER COLUMN id_category DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE question ALTER COLUMN id_creator DROP DEFAULT;
```

Comment: thanks for helping. this number is incrementing after every attemp to INSERT

Comment: I think those columns have been incorrectly set to `serial`.  That means that if the value isn't explicitely specified when inserting a row, it will pick the next value from its sequence.  For columns that reference a column on another table, that shouldn't be the case.  Those should just be int columns without a sequence.  You can disable the sequences, and I'll update my answer with the DDL for that.

Comment: I solved it another way setting all foreign keys from all tables in INSERT definition. But I do think that it is not a pretty solution

Comment: I would still suggest you drop the defaults on those columns as the sequence doesn't serve a purpose.

Comment: yes, but difficulty level I must pass every time I guess.

Comment: Yes, correct.  And that difficulty level id has to be present in the difficulty table, otherwise you end up with the error message you got.

Answer (score 1):

[Postgres now recommends using `generated always as` instead of `serial`.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial)  If you do this, then the types will align much more simply:

```
CREATE TABLE question (
  id int generated always as identity PRIMARY KEY,
  text varchar,
  correct_answer varchar,
  incorrect_answer1 varchar,
  incorrect_answer2 varchar,
  incorrect_answer3 varchar,
  id_difficulty int REFERENCES difficulty(id),
  id_category int REFERENCES category (id),
  id_creator int REFERENCES game (id)
);

CREATE TABLE difficulty (
  id int generated always as identity PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar
);
```

This makes what is happening much clearer.  The data type for a foreign key reference needs to match the data type of the primary key.  Postgres knows that `serial` is really `int`.  But using `generated always`, it is obvious that they are the same.

In addition, `generated always as` is more consistent with standard SQL.